# how to write a value in a column under condition?

Tags: python, database, multiple-columns, addition

I've to write different values in a specific column under a condition.
Here a visual example of the problem:

[In the column D, I have to add a value XX if the time range is between 10:00 and 10:30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrioQ.png)

I've tried in this way

```
def function (df, name=['column'], name_app1=['column1']): 
    for row in df[name]:
        if [(df[name].dt.hour >= 10) & (df[name].dt.hour <= 11)]:
          df[name_app1].append('0.400')
```

but I obtain always an error
 `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Answer (score 0):

```
df[name_app1].append('0.400')
```

In this line you are trying to write single value to complete column. This is the error.

Use this

```
def function (df, name=['column'], name_app1=['column1']): 
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        if [(df.loc[i,name].dt.hour >= 00) & (df.loc[i,name].dt.hour <= 3)]:
          df.loc[i, name_app1] = '0.400'
```

Let me know if you need further help

Comment: I've tried but this error shows:  'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'. If I remove .dt it works but the code write the value everywhere and not in the right positions